# VBA EXCEL save as .pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I do have a problem i can not solve with my excel experience capacities. I would like to save a range of cells from one Sheet to a .pdf.
The name should be as values in some cells. The place where to save is just the folder where the Excel file is located.
I do not know where my problem is. Here is my code.

But there is always a Run-Time erroe 5. Invalid procedure call or argument.

Thank you in advance.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:K49")

Dim ID As String
Dim DIR As String

ID = Range("E5").Value & "_" & Range("E7").Value

DIR = ActiveWorkbook.Path

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Path, vbInformation, "Workbook Path"
    
rng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=DIR + ID + ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: First step, use `&` to concatenate instead of `+`. Next, probably missing a backslash between `Dir` and `ID`.

Comment: Ahh so that what you was trying to write @BigBen . I saw the first edit and it was confusing. I believe you need to double the backslash within the code marks. Hopefully like this: ``\``. Ok I was wrong double code marks on each side and only one backslash

Comment: @Andreas - yeah I always forget / never attempt to figure out how many backticks are necessary.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can always debug your code yourself first before writing a question. A simple `msgbox DIR` and `msgbox ID` would have showed you what the values are, which is also helpful to include in the question.

Comment: Now that i use this code:     

rng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="DIR" \ "ID" & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

it writes "type mismatch"

Comment: Missing some `&`, and messed up quotes. `Filename:=DIR & "\" & ID & ".pdf"`

Comment: Thank you BigBen and Andreas. But, still not working.

Comment: Debugging hint: use `Debug.Print DIR & "\" & ID & ".pdf"` and check the output in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Nothing, the "immediate" window does not pop up.. i work with Excel 2007. Might that be an issue?

Comment: Found the Immediate window. And it shows this: C:\VUJE\Napätie\1TJ41U01-Ohyb 90°-uzol L05N_Hydroskuska.pdf. But when it gets to the code where it shoud export a pdf it stops and writes nothing else. (Made a debug.print at the end to tell me if it got there)

Comment: Thank you @Bigben. The problem was my oldish PC at home. I did not had the expansion in my office "save as PDF". The code works now, working at my work PC.